# Problems with subtitles with Windows Media Player and DLNA

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, windows-media-player, tv, dlna

Not sure if this is the right place for this, but this is super frustrating.  Trying to get subtitles to play on my Samsung LED TV via DLNA (TV and computer on same network).  TV sees the files and plays the movie just fine, but does not load the subtitles file (.srt).

Furthermore, the subtitles also don't show up in Windows Media player either (yes, the show subtitles option is checked).

Finally, to add to the confusion VLC player DOES correctly show the subtitles.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... I've watched other movies with subtitles with this same setup and its worked fine... Any thoughts?

File Setup:

```
The.Movie.Name.MP4
The.Movie.Name.MP4.MTA
The.Movie.Name.SRT
```

Comment: Have you tried using VLC DLNA's capability to see if you different results?

Comment: No, how would I go about doing that? Not super familiar with VLC

Comment: I have the same problem... Finally got the SRT subs to work with WMP, but they are not streamed to my WD TV Live player

Answer (score 4):

To get SRT subtitles in WMP, you can install the [Local Subtitles for WMP](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wmpsub/) plug-in.